# does algebra over algebraically closed field has isomorphism classes of irreducible modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field and $M$ be an F-algebra. Which are the conditions that make $M$ has finitely many isomorphism classes of irreducible $M$-modules?

Comment: What sort of conditions do you have in mind?  I don't think there's any particularly nice necessary and sufficient conditions in general.

Comment: So, We can say that any algebra over algebraically closed field has finitely many isomorphism classes of irreducible modules?

Comment: No, that's certainly not true, e.g. take $M = F[x]$. It is true if $M$ is finite-dimensional over $F$. (Also, $M$ is a bad name for an algebra, since usually in this context $M$ refers to a module.)